# JAVAFX 2.0 How can i change the slider icon in a slider to an image?

Tags: icons, slider, javafx

I want to change the icon to my image, I've looked through the CSS reference guide but I can't seem to find anything relevant. Is it even possible? Doesn't matter if it is using CSS or declaratively from main JavaFX script.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the sample code and images of how a custom slider is rendered in this [AudioPlayer](http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/fun-javafx-2-0-audio-player/).

Also the [JFXtras library](http://jfxtras.org/) has numerous gauges if you just want feedback rather than an interactive control.

Here is some sample css using the selector pointed out by invariant's answer.  Note that I needed to add an -fx-padding specification at half the images dimensions in order for the whole image to display.

```
/** slider.css
place in same directory as SliderCss.java
ensure build system copies the css file to the build output path */

.slider .thumb {
    -fx-background-image :url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/diagram-free/128/piggy-bank-icon.png");   
    -fx-padding: 64;
}
/* Icon license: creative commons with attribution: http://www.doublejdesign.co.uk/products-page/icons/diagram */
```

Sample app:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SliderCss extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    VBox layout = new VBox();
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10px;");
    layout.getChildren().setAll(new Slider());
    layout.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("slider.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));

    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Sample program output:

[image: piggy]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

you can change thumb of slider using css

```
.slider .thumb{
 -fx-background-image :url("your image");   
 ...// more customization       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question but I think I have a contribution to this solution.

If we want to use a unique slider or we want to modify the appearance of all the sliders the previous solution is more than enough. However, if we need only modify the appearance of only one slider the we need another approach.

What we gonna do is imagine that we have applied a based style to the main `scene`. But we don't want to add another `css` file just to modify the behavior of the slider. So the question is: **How we can modify the slider style using our base `css` file?**

The solution is simple `setId()` all the controls have this attribute. Now let's check out this class:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by teocci.
 *
 * @author teocci@yandex.com on 2018-Jul-06
 */
public class CustomSliderThumb extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setId("custom-slider");

        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.setId("base-layout");
        layout.getChildren().setAll(slider);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("css/style.css");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

In this example, we created a `slider` and set its `id` as `"custom-slider"`. Then we added this slider to a `VBox` layout and, finally, we added the layout to the scene that has the `style.css`

Now lets check the `style.css` and how to use the id selector to apply a custom style. Remember to specify `-fx-pref-height` and `-fx-pref-width` with the dimensions of the image or if is a square `-fx-padding` at half the image side dimension for displaying the whole image.

```css
#custom-slider .thumb {
    -fx-background-image :url("https://i.imgur.com/SwDjIg7.png");
    -fx-background-color: transparent;

    -fx-padding: 24;

    /*-fx-pref-height: 48;*/
    /*-fx-pref-width: 48;*/
}

#custom-slider .track {
    -fx-background-color: #2F2F2F;
}

#base-layout {
    -fx-background-color: lightgray;
    -fx-padding: 10px;
}
```

Sample program output:

[image: slider]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the thumb background color and only have the image(semi-transparent ones like round button) then you should also     -fx-background-color:transparent; unless you will have the background

```
.slider .thumb {
    -fx-background-image :url("sider-round-thumb-image.png"); 
    -fx-padding: 16; /* My thumb image is 33x33 pixels,so padding is half */
    -fx-pref-height: 28;
    -fx-pref-width: 28;

    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
```